# IIS 8 - Not finding default.html when using SSL certificate

Tags: html, vb.net, ssl, ssl-certificate, iis-8

I've created a webapp and a console application to register the website in the IIS.
There seems to be no problem there at all.

This is the code I use for registering the website in the IIS.

```
Dim manager As New ServerManager
Dim site As Site = manager.Sites.Add("MyControl", "http", "*:80:test.localhost", "C:\\inetpub\wwwroot\MyControl")

manager.ApplicationPools.Add("MyControl")
site.ApplicationDefaults.ApplicationPoolName = "MyControl"

manager.CommitChanges()
```

The site is registered fine in the IIS. Type being http, hostname being test.localhost, port being 80 and the ip being *. Like expected.

I've modified my hosts file, added the line: `127.0.0.1 test.localhost` so that navigating to http://test.localhost will resolve in a redirect to our site on the IIS.

This should mean redirecting to our default page default.html which is in the root of inetpub/wwwroot/MyControl.

This doesn't happen however. I get a blank page and no title and the source is blank, but not a page not found.
Furthermore, if I navigate to http://test.localhost/default.html myself, I get a blank page, but a title saying: MyControl. And if I now take a look at the source, I can see that it finds the file, but nothing is displayed.

If I set up the website in the IIS manually, there's no problem.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

EDIT:

So far, so good.
I've now made it work with the above code. What happened you ask? I have no clue.

Now I need to use the same website, but install it with an SSL-certificate.

I'm using this code

```
Module Main
<DllImport("advapi32.DLL", SetLastError:=True)>
Public Function LogonUser(ByVal username As String, ByVal domain As String,
                          ByVal password As String, ByVal logonType As Integer, ByVal logonProvider As Integer,
                          ByRef token As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function

Sub Main()
    'Load indstillinger fra app.config
    Dim sslPath As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("sslPath")
    Dim sslPassword As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("sslPassword")
    Dim remoteUsername As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("remoteUsername")
    Dim remotePassword As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("remotePassword")

    'Lav en store, således at vi kan få fat i vores ssl certifikat
    Dim store As X509Store = New X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine)
    store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly Or OpenFlags.ReadWrite)

    'Generer credentials til impersonation
    Dim adminToken As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
    Dim admin As WindowsIdentity = Nothing
    Dim context As WindowsImpersonationContext = Nothing

    'Login med den specificerede bruger
    LogonUser(remoteUsername, System.Environment.MachineName, remotePassword, 9, 0, adminToken) '9 afspejler logintype og 0 afspejler loginprovider - Ingen idé om hvad det har af betydning
    admin = New WindowsIdentity(adminToken)
    context = admin.Impersonate()

    'Import af SSL certifikat
    Dim certificate As X509Certificate2 = New X509Certificate2(sslPath, sslPassword) 'Sti til SSL certifikat og password til at installere dette
    store.Add(certificate)

    'Opret en manager og en config til oprettelse af site
    Dim manager As New ServerManager
    Dim config As Microsoft.Web.Administration.Configuration = manager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration()

    'Opret site i IIS med det valgte certifikat
    Dim site As Site = manager.Sites.Add("MyControl", "*:443:webmail.jcdhotel.dk", "C:\\inetpub\wwwroot\MyControl", certificate.GetCertHash())

    'Kræv SSL
    Dim accessSection As Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/access", "MyControl")
    accessSection("sslFlags") = "Ssl"

    'Opret en applicationpool specifikt til MyControl og sæt denne til default
    manager.ApplicationPools.Add("MyControl")
    site.ApplicationDefaults.ApplicationPoolName = "MyControl"

    'Luk store
    store.Close()

    'Gem ændringer og revert impersonation
    manager.CommitChanges()
    context.Undo()
End Sub
```

Again. The code is registering the website in the IIS and sets the certificate just fine. The binding looks like this

[image: Error]

I have again modified my hosts file, adding the line `127.0.0.1 webmail.jcdhotel.dk`

I can go to the link https://webmail.jcdhotel.dk and recieve a blank page and the source being blank. I can then go to https://webmail.jcdhotel.dk/default.html and the title will be set and I can now check the source but the page is still blank.

Again, any help is appreciated and thank you in advance!

EDIT:

New information. By manually trying to add the website to IIS with the SSL certificate, I recieve the following error:

[image: SSL Error]

Hopefully this will help shed some light on the problem.

EDIT:

Last edit, hopefully :D

I can now manually add a binding using the SSL certificate. The problem was due to the certificate being installed incorrectly. Which leads me to the final hurdle.

When adding the certificate to the store using vb.net. How do I check the "Allow certificate to be exported"? - Since that solved my problem when adding the certificate manually.

Comment: I would first remove the certificate and WindowsIndentity bits and make sure that the creation of the site works fine and reliable. Then add SSL and test again. Finally add the WindowsIndentity. You want to find out which part works and which doesn't. Also I would perform the same steps manually and then compare the ApplicationHost.config.

Comment: I made it worked without SSL and WindowsIndentity (See before my edit). I've tried removing the WindowsIdentity from the my code, but it still won't budge :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying, what seemed to be everything, I ended up with this code

```
<DllImport("advapi32.DLL", SetLastError:=True)>
Public Function LogonUser(ByVal username As String, ByVal domain As String,
                          ByVal password As String, ByVal logonType As Integer, ByVal logonProvider As Integer,
                          ByRef token As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function

Sub Main()
    'Load indstillinger fra app.config
    Dim sslPath As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("sslPath")
    Dim sslPassword As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("sslPassword")
    Dim remoteUsername As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("remoteUsername")
    Dim remotePassword As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("remotePassword")

    'Lav en store, således at vi kan få fat i vores ssl certifikat
    Dim store As X509Store = New X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine)

    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite)

    'Generer credentials til impersonation
    Dim adminToken As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
    Dim admin As WindowsIdentity = Nothing
    Dim context As WindowsImpersonationContext = Nothing

    'Login med den specificerede bruger
    LogonUser(remoteUsername, System.Environment.MachineName, remotePassword, 9, 0, adminToken) '9 afspejler logintype og 0 afspejler loginprovider - Ingen idé om hvad det har af betydning
    admin = New WindowsIdentity(adminToken)
    context = admin.Impersonate()

    'Import af SSL certifikat
    Dim certificate As X509Certificate2 = New X509Certificate2(sslPath, sslPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet) 'Sti til SSL certifikat og password til at installere dette

    store.Add(certificate)

    'Opret en manager og en config til oprettelse af site
    Using manager As New ServerManager
        Dim config As Microsoft.Web.Administration.Configuration = manager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration()

        'Opret site i IIS med det valgte certifikat
        Dim site As Site = manager.Sites.Add("MyControl", "*:443:webmail.jcdhotel.dk", "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyControl", certificate.GetCertHash())

        'Kræv SSL
        Dim accessSection As Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/access", "MyControl")
        accessSection("sslFlags") = "Ssl"

        'Opret en applicationpool specifikt til MyControl og sæt denne til default
        manager.ApplicationPools.Add("MyControl")
        site.ApplicationDefaults.ApplicationPoolName = "MyControl"

        'Luk store
        store.Close()

        'Gem ændringer og revert impersonation
        manager.CommitChanges()
        context.Undo()
    End Using
End Sub
```

The problem was in the line

```
Dim site As Site = manager.Sites.Add("MyControl", "*:443:webmail.jcdhotel.dk", "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyControl", certificate.GetCertHash())
```

I'm used to C# and how you escape strings. So I had falsely popped in an extra \ making the line look like this

`Dim site As Site = manager.Sites.Add("MyControl", "*:443:webmail.jcdhotel.dk", "C:\\inetpub\wwwroot\MyControl", certificate.GetCertHash())`